# Javascript array reverse confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

In the following example, when I log to the console, I get ["c","b","a"] for all three arrays.

```
let x = Array.from("abc");
let y = x;
let z = y.reverse();
console.log({x:x, y:y, z:z})
```

y = ["c", "b", "a"] because Array.prototype.reverse() reverses the array **in place**

z = ["c", "b", "a"] because I reversed y and then assigned it to z

but why does x = ["c", "b", "a"]?

Comment: you do not assign a new array, but took the same object reference.

Comment: you need to do deep copy if you want to keep original

Comment: no, you don't need a deep copy - a shallow copy is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script only ever creates a single array:

```
let x = Array.from("abc");
```

The `Array.from` creates the array and assigns it to `x`.

```
let y = x;
```

The above creates the `y` variable name and points it to the same array.

```
let z = y.reverse();
```

The above reverses the array in-place, and also creates the `z` variable name and points it to said array.

The array is never cloned, so `x`, `y`, and `z` are all referring to the same array in memory.

Comment: I figured this is what was happening. Is there a way to check whether two variables point to the same object in memory?

Comment: Something like `x === y`

Answer (score 1):

when you are assigning y = x you are passing reference of x. So copy x by spread operator.

```js
let x = Array.from("abc");
let y = [...x];
let z = y.reverse();
console.log({x:x, y:y, z:z})
```